# d3 csv data loading

Tags: javascript, html, csv, d3.js

I am trying to adapt a simple scatterplot program in D3 to accept a CSV file. When I use the data in the file it works just fine, but when I try to load the CSV file it simply won't work. Is there something simple I am missing? The contents of the CSV file "datatest.csv" are the same as the dataset in the code. I have checked that the browser is loading the data, and it seems to all be there. I figure I'm simply missing a step.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>D3 Demo: Linear scales</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../d3/d3.v3.js"></script>
    <style type="text/css">
        /* No style rules here yet */       
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <script type="text/javascript">

        //Width and height
        var w = 900;
        var h = 500;
        var padding = 20;
        var dataset = [];

//          var dataset = [
//                          [5, 20], [480, 90], [250, 50], [100, 33], [330, 95],
//                          [410, 12], [475, 44], [25, 67], [85, 21], [220, 88],
//                          [600, 150]
//                        ];

        d3.csv("datatest.csv", function(data) {
        dataset=data
        });



        //Create scale functions
        var xScale = d3.scale.linear()
                             .domain([0, d3.max(dataset, function(d) { return d[0]; })])
                             .range([padding, w - padding * 2]);

        var yScale = d3.scale.linear()
                             .domain([0, d3.max(dataset, function(d) { return d[1]; })])
                             .range([h - padding, padding]);

        var rScale = d3.scale.linear()
                             .domain([0, d3.max(dataset, function(d) { return d[1]; })])
                             .range([2, 5]);

        //Create SVG element
        var svg = d3.select("body")
                    .append("svg")
                    .attr("width", w)
                    .attr("height", h);

        svg.selectAll("circle")
           .data(dataset)
           .enter()
           .append("circle")
           .attr("cx", function(d) {
                return xScale(d[0]);
           })
           .attr("cy", function(d) {
                return yScale(d[1]);
           })
           .attr("r", function(d) {
                return rScale(d[1]);
           });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

This is the content of the CSV file:

```
x-coordinate, y-coordinate
5,20
480,90
250,50
100,33
330,95
410,12
475,44
25,67
85,21
220,88
600,150
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

**IMPORTANT:**

While the answer here works, there's a builtin method `d3.csv.parseRows()`, which achieves the same result. For that, see @ryanmt's answer (also on this page). However, keep in mind that regardless of the method you use, if your CSV has numbers in it then you'll need to convert them from strings to javascript Numbers. You can do it by prefixing the parsed values with a `+`. For example, in the solution I provided here — which doesn't use `parseRows()` — that conversion is achieved via `+d["x-coordinate"]`.

**THE ANSWER:**

The CSV parser produces an array of objects, rather than the array of arrays that you need. It looks like this:

```
[
  {"x-coordinate":"5"," y-coordinate":"20"},
  {"x-coordinate":"480"," y-coordinate":"90"},
  {"x-coordinate":"250"," y-coordinate":"50"},
  {"x-coordinate":"100"," y-coordinate":"33"},
  ...
]
```

To transform it, you need to use a `map()` function:

```
d3.csv("datatest.csv", function(data) {
  dataset = data.map(function(d) { return [ +d["x-coordinate"], +d["y-coordinate"] ]; });
});
```

(Note, `map()` is not available in older IE. If that matters, then there are plenty of workarounds with d3, jQuery, etc)

Comment: In the csv file I have the information in the dataset set up as a comma separated list. each array in the dataset has its own line in the external file. The CSV file is setup correctly, I can't figure out how to get the information out of the file properly

Comment: @EnglishGrad Does the first line of your CSV have column names? d3's csv parser assumes that this first line's values correspond to property names. It uses those property names to produce an array of objects –– not of Arrays. Based on my understanding of what you're describing, there's no way it's going to work the way you have it. Try `console.log`'ing the data and see what you get.

Comment: Meetamit, thanks for the help. I have posted the contents of the CSV file above

Comment: I consoled logged the data and it looks fine. I can't figure out why it won't plot

Comment: @EnglishGrad K, I think this is the solutions (see edited answer).

Comment: Thanks again meetamit. It loads the data with this but only produces one data point in the graph. do I nee to loop through the structure as well?

Comment: @EnglishGrad Ok, yeah, there are still a couple of problems. First, in the CSV's first line, you need to remove the space after the comma, before "y-coordinate" (if that's somehow not possible, the code needs to account for the space: `d[" y-coordinate"]`, but that's pretty weird). Next, you need to convert the values from strings (as they are in the CSV) to numbers. The quick way to do it is to add `+` before each one (I modified the code to show this).

Comment: What does the `+d` stand for?

Comment: It's a trick for coercing strings into numbers. Since this is a csv, all the values come in as strings that need to be coerced. I can't remember off the top of my head whether coercing a non-numeric string in this way yield `NaN` or preserves the string (probably the former), so have to be careful with it.

Comment: I get an error code when trying the initial code with the code above : XMLHttpRequest cannot load .../datatest.csv. Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http, data, chrome, chrome-extension, https, chrome-extension-resource.

Comment: @Selrac, sounds like the csv is hosted on a different domain than your website (or localhost), and browsers purposely prevent that, for security reasons. It's unrelated to and/or is more general than this here question about csv parsing. You either have to move/copy your csv to the same domain, or (harder) write a proxy server. Research cross origin requests.

Answer (score 7):

D3 provides a builtin for this very thing.

Instead of calling `.parse()` on your data, call `.parseRows`.  This provides just the data as an Array, rather than an Object (based upon the header line).

see the [Documentation](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/CSV).

Comment: Could you give an example of it working with `.parseRows`? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Using d3.csvParseRows (assuming D3 v5)

```
d3.text('/data/output.csv')
  .then( text => d3.csvParseRows(text) )
  .then( d => console.log(d) );
```