# unable to load csv to d3 scatter plot

Tags: javascript, csv, d3.js

Below is my d3 code, it works perfectly if I mention the dataset with its numbers. However, when i want to take data from a csv file, it doesn't not accept it.

*ERROR

```
Error: Invalid value for <circle> attribute cx="NaN"
```

Here how the csv looks like:

```
t       Or
16610   20635
14920   19532
13131   14814
15882   15745
15769   14993
15989   22557
14895   15387
17915   19758
```

Although if I try in google chrome,

```
console.log(dataset)
```

I get the data from csv but when i run it to apply, it just doesn't work in the browser.

I am using brackets as my IDE and google chrome as my default browser.

```
<body>

<h1> Hello World!! </h1>

<script type="text/javascript">

var dataset;
d3.csv("t.csv", function(d) {

dataset = d;

var h = 500;
var w = 1200;

var padding = 30;

var xscale = d3.scale.linear()
.domain([0,d3.max(dataset, function(d) { return d[0];})])
.range([padding, w- padding*2]);

var yscale = d3.scale.linear()
.domain([0, d3.max(dataset, function(d) { return d[1];})])
.range([h-padding,padding]);

var rscale = d3.scale.linear()
.domain([0,d3.max(dataset , function(d) { return d[1];})])
.range([5,30]);

var xAxis   = d3.svg.axis()
.scale(xscale)
.orient("bottom");

var svg = d3.select("body")
.append("svg")
.attr("width", w)
.attr("height", h);


var circle = svg.selectAll("circle")
.data(dataset)
.enter()
.append("circle")
.attr("cx", function(d) { return xscale(d[0]);})
.attr("cy", function(d) { return yscale(d[1]);})
.attr("r",function(d) { return rscale(d[1]);})
.on("mouseover", function(){d3.select(this).style("fill", "yellow");})
.on("mouseout", function(){d3.select(this).style("fill", function(dataset) { return "rgb(0,0," +(d*10) + ")";});});

var text = svg.selectAll("text")
.data(dataset)
.enter()
.append("text")
.text(function(d) { return d[0] + "," + d[1];})
.attr("x", function(d) { return xscale(d[0]);})
.attr("y", function(d) { return yscale(d[1]);})
.attr("font-family", "sans-serif")
.attr("font-size", "11px")
.attr("fill" ,"red");

svg.append("g")
.attr("class", "axis")
.attr("transform", "translate(0, " + (h - padding) +")")
.call(xAxis);           
});

</script> 


</body>
```

Comment: Are you getting any error messages? What does your CSV look like?

Comment: I have just added the csv part and the error

Comment: The numbers in the CSV (which doesn't look like a CSV but a TSV BTW) are read as strings. You need to convert them to numbers. See e.g. [this example](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/3884955).

Comment: I used this code as suggested by this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14986435/d3-csv-data-loading?rq=1)                                                       d3.csv("t.csv", function(error, d) {
dataset = d.map(function(d) { return [ +d["t"], +d["or"] ]; }); now d3 plots but for one column and it doesnt for the other column which is r and y values for my circles. as far as csv is concerned i saved my excel file as a csv.

Comment: The above code i mentioned worked, Thanks for your inputs though..

Comment: `d3.csv` won't load the file as you've pasted it correctly. Use `d3.tsv` instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just tweaked my above code. using the below which i found right [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14986435/d3-csv-data-loading?rq=1)

It worked

```
var dataset;

d3.csv("t.csv", function(error, d) {
  dataset = d.map(function(d) { return [ +d["t"], +d["Or"] ]; });
```