# D3 tutorial doesn't work on local machine

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I am trying to teach myself D3 and I'm using the highly-rated Curran Kelleher's Intro to D3 ([GitHub Page](https://github.com/curran/screencasts/tree/gh-pages/introToD3))

I'm currently stuck on reading/parsing data from CSV files. His code and expected output are here ([D3 Example Code](http://curran.github.io/screencasts/introToD3/examples/viewer/#/73)).

EDIT:: Copied/Pasted my code here:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>D3 tutorial 10</title>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/4.12.0/d3.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<script>
var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
        .attr("width",  250)
        .attr("height", 250);

      var xScale = d3.scaleLinear().range([0, 250]);
      var yScale = d3.scaleLinear().range([0, 250]);

      function render(data){

        xScale.domain(d3.extent(data, function (d){ return d.sepal_length; }));
        yScale.domain(d3.extent(data, function (d){ return d.petal_length; }));

        var circles = svg.selectAll("circle").data(data);
        circles.enter().append("circle").attr("r", 10);
        circles
          .attr("cx", function (d){ return xScale(d.sepal_length); })
          .attr("cy", function (d){ return yScale(d.petal_length); });

        circles.exit().remove();
      }

      function type(d){
        d.sepal_length = +d.sepal_length;
        d.sepal_width  = +d.sepal_width;
        d.petal_length = +d.petal_length;
        d.petal_width  = +d.petal_width;
        return d;
      }

      d3.csv("iris.csv", type, render);
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

I've copied and pasted his code exactly the same in my d3.html page but this is the output I'm getting in my Chrome browser window. Any ideas on where I went wrong?
[image: My Output]

Comment: I see there is a iris.csv data file - you have it also available for your code?

Comment: yes - it's in the same folder as the .html file

Comment: If you copy exactly the example I don’t see any faults at first glance. I would recommend to play with numbers such as circle radius or area margins and look if it has some effect. If nothing help I’ll try this example tomorrow.

Comment: Also see pretty good items: http://learnjsdata.com/read_data.html,   and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14986435/d3-csv-data-loading and http://www.tutorialsteacher.com/d3js/loading-data-from-file-in-d3js

Comment: I think you may start with his easier example of d3 and csv - http://curran.github.io/screencasts/introToD3/examples/viewer/#/69. Here is this fully working example on Plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/GeBxKTRk0Jq3e6AHayny. Press Run and you will see correct result, data.csv is a data file from the example.

Comment: The problem here is just the reference to D3. Please show us exactly the script reference you're using.

Comment: @GerardoFurtado I've edited my original post with my exact code

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### The magic of enter.append()

For anyone debugging a D3 dataviz, there is a very important information here: the circles **were appended**. You can see them at the origin (0,0).

This fact eliminates a series of other problems, like the CSV not being loaded, the library not being referenced, the lack of a web server etc...

Elements pilling up at the origin is a symptom of different problems. Normally, the culprit is a `NaN` somewhere. But the problem here is more subtle:

The issue is that you're using D3 v4, when you should use D3 v3, which is the version used by the author of that code.

These are the lines that worked with v3 but won't work with v4:

```
var circles = svg.selectAll("circle").data(data);
circles.enter().append("circle").attr("r", 10);
circles.attr("cx", function(d) {
        return xScale(d.sepal_length);
    })
    .attr("cy", function(d) {
        return yScale(d.petal_length);
    });
```

Let's comment what's happening here. This is the "update" selection:

```
var circles = svg.selectAll("circle").data(data);
```

And this is the "enter" selection:

```
circles.enter().append("circle").attr("r", 10);
```

Now, pay attention to this: you are setting the positions to the **"update"** selection, not to the "enter" one:

```
circles.attr("cx", function(d) {
        return xScale(d.sepal_length);
    })
    .attr("cy", function(d) {
        return yScale(d.petal_length);
    });
```

That won't work in D3 v4. According to [Mike Bostock](https://medium.com/@mbostock/what-makes-software-good-943557f8a488), D3 creator:

> D3 2.0 introduced a change to address this duplication: appending to the enter selection would now copy entering elements into the update selection. Thus, any operations applied to the update selection after appending to the enter selection would apply to both entering and updating elements, and duplicate code could be eliminated [...] D3 4.0 removes the magic of enter.append. In fact, D3 4.0 removes the distinction between enter and normal selections entirely: there is now only one class of selection.

That is the *"magic of enter.append()"*, which works in v2 and v3, but not anymore in v4.

**Solution:**

Just use D3 v3.

Alternatively, if you want to keep v4, just merge the selections:

```
var circles = svg.selectAll("circle").data(data);
circles.enter().append("circle").attr("r", 10).merge(circles)
    .attr("cx", function(d) {
        return xScale(d.sepal_length);
    })
    .attr("cy", function(d) {
        return yScale(d.petal_length);
    });

circles.exit().remove();
```

Here is that code working with v4: https://bl.ocks.org/anonymous/6f7a7e1bbc682097932d49b0a13221fc/dda68f134c57dc68b7469d10206280ea1a8d610a

Comment: Yup, that was my issue. Now my solution matches the example and expected output. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

I see @Gerardo already answered. However, when I was learning D3.js, I found it very useful to code in version 4, even if the tutorials were in version 3, and try to recode these tutorials to make them work.

This one was very straightforward. The only significant change is nomenclature: `d3.scale.linear()` becomes `d3.scaleLinear()`. Assigning data properties is simpler, too (after entering the data, you can add the circles' properties immediately, without needing to reselect the circles).

The v4 code is below. I also removed one line -- the one that reads `circles.exit().remove();` -- because it's not relevant to this tutorial!

```
<script>
  var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
    .attr("width",  250)
    .attr("height", 250);

  var xScale = d3.scaleLinear().range([0, 250]);
  var yScale = d3.scaleLinear().range([0, 250]);

  function render(data) {

    xScale.domain(d3.extent(data, function(d) { return d.sepal_length; }));
    yScale.domain(d3.extent(data, function(d) { return d.petal_length; }));

    var circles = svg.selectAll("circle")
      .data(data)
      .enter().append("circle")
        .attr("r", 10)
        .attr("cx", function (d) { return xScale(d.sepal_length); })
        .attr("cy", function (d) { return yScale(d.petal_length); });
  }

  function type(d) {
    d.sepal_length = +d.sepal_length;
    d.sepal_width  = +d.sepal_width;
    d.petal_length = +d.petal_length;
    d.petal_width  = +d.petal_width;
    return d;
  }

   d3.csv("iris.csv", type, render);

 </script>
```

It produces [this output](https://markusmannheim.github.io/Stackoverflow-basic-scatter-plot/). Try to learn v4 coding from the beginning. It'll save you time in the end!